# RSA-SHA256 with PSS padding invalid signature error on json data types but work on simple string (go lang againt python)

Tags: python, go, cryptography, rsa

I have to assign signature from json data objects in python and verify it in go lang or vise versa

It works if assigning and verification is on the same language or using input data as string but fails if input data is dictionary

Private key

```
    -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Public key

```
    -----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBCgKCAQEA0DFzgagqwMPnPzeMpUldQRrdo2cmAzy/akPl05Rz0IzPms5Q/dl4
un1QMwQQRHKEDsJIrcCTOEsqtK/XG35Za9GsVxkoTuNPtDj8TpyvDHajPt3htqCI
a2wRTsdvQIveVRixyCnsaR+crykpK8hOc7lG9Zh1l+9Y2Kb5shtWd/nXpUDW2YXM
nz2RWTmGhChsiW7VP52pH4tM870NTMKHW6tJJIdAYU47hToqe+uKaQ1x28GK5+Bb
C9PWZwjKWyTJ5k5DmhR3LZc6jJOVMJvwdTOvqogwD7dcMgjx/VF8D4I6Z1F36UrB
+JZC3oroU8E6ue29zJPSL0+5gVrkn+eN2wIDAQAB
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

python assigning data

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes, serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
import base64
import json
from cryptography.exceptions import InvalidSignature


user = {"name": "Foo", "age": 12, "email": "foo@gmail.com"}

def sign_user(message) -> str:
    message_json = json.dumps(message)
    message_byts = message_json.encode("utf-8")
    key_file = open("private_key.pem", "rb")
    private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(
        key_file.read(), password=None, backend=default_backend()
    )
    signature = private_key.sign(
        message_byts,
        padding.PSS(
            mgf=padding.MGF1(hashes.SHA256()), salt_length=padding.PSS.MAX_LENGTH
        ),
        hashes.SHA256(),
    )

    signature_base64 = base64.b64encode(signature).decode("utf-8")
    print("\n\n", signature_base64, "\n\n")
    return signature_base64
```

Created signature from python `DReue2qd0Ir/TEQ5rDtegBSqgINIG+LqMnliwh3YbVUlb58TwfrcO1jWvR55LoBa524Fc2ZnWms3g7T2BFxlMxBAU8fFkZ33TYP7VTeImOiP2QThKeQZ11nzr8LjbPnimOj2+2YMXxrP0lTGvf69A5vpXhnPWa+jBXnyoHlw8cJL971FDfUwB7T3SQg+HIEmWk1xEjRedQzyLW+kAAICoeP8u9ClCJgdnd7a2IRDzJQ2A/OhrZaiwdSwrvCmiT9iezOT3t5yCiC/VkzL1BUQx3hl7AGSwzbKmoYqK+9USXkYNmjdOaUQMfql8p1cu46D3DF59dyRS6NWCZ54SkSyTg==`

then verification in golang

Verify function

```
package certificate

import (
    "crypto"
    "crypto/rand"
    "crypto/rsa"
    "crypto/sha256"
    "crypto/x509"
    "encoding/base64"
    "encoding/pem"
    "os"

    "github.com/goccy/go-json"
    "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2/log"
)

func VerifySignature(encodedSignature string, message []byte) (bool, error) {
    // Decode signature
    decodedSignature, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(encodedSignature)
    if err != nil {
        log.Error(err)
        return false, err
    }
    // Load the public key from the file
    publicKeyFile, err := os.ReadFile(publicKeyName)
    if err != nil {
        log.Error(err)
        return false, err
    }

    publicKeyBlock, _ := pem.Decode(publicKeyFile)
    rsaKey, err := x509.ParsePKCS1PublicKey(publicKeyBlock.Bytes)
    if err != nil {
        log.Error(err)
        return false, err
    }

    // Hash the mesage usign SHA-256
    hash := sha256.New()
    hash.Write(message)
    hashedMessage := hash.Sum(nil)

    passOptions := rsa.PSSOptions{
        SaltLength: rsa.PSSSaltLengthAuto,
        Hash:       crypto.SHA256,
    }
    err = rsa.VerifyPSS(rsaKey, crypto.SHA256, hashedMessage[:], decodedSignature, &passOptions)
    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }

    return true, nil
}

type User struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Age uint `json:"age"`
    Email string `json:"email"`
}
var simpleUser = User{Name: "Foo", Age: 12, Email: "foo@gmail.com"}




func verifySignatureUser(sign string, data User){
    dataBytes, err := json.Marshal(data)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)
    }
    verified, err := VerifySignature(sign, dataBytes)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(verified)
}


func SimpleTest() {
    var signature = "DReue2qd0Ir/TEQ5rDtegBSqgINIG+LqMnliwh3YbVUlb58TwfrcO1jWvR55LoBa524Fc2ZnWms3g7T2BFxlMxBAU8fFkZ33TYP7VTeImOiP2QThKeQZ11nzr8LjbPnimOj2+2YMXxrP0lTGvf69A5vpXhnPWa+jBXnyoHlw8cJL971FDfUwB7T3SQg+HIEmWk1xEjRedQzyLW+kAAICoeP8u9ClCJgdnd7a2IRDzJQ2A/OhrZaiwdSwrvCmiT9iezOT3t5yCiC/VkzL1BUQx3hl7AGSwzbKmoYqK+9USXkYNmjdOaUQMfql8p1cu46D3DF59dyRS6NWCZ54SkSyTg=="
    verifySignatureUser(signature, simpleUser)
}
```

but using with string data types everything works perfect.

Comment: `json.dumps(message)` does not produce the same output as  `json.Marshal(data)`.   Print the JSON in each program to observe the difference.

Comment: What is equivalent of that in go @CeriseLimón

Comment: @LuqmanJr: Please see [json canonicalization](https://www.google.com/search?q=json+canonicalization). There is a standard for this and there are packages for both Python and Go implementing this standard.

Comment: Thanks @SteffenUllrich I have resolved it https://github.com/cyberphone/json-canonicalization